# Create an xml file in Haskell without using XML library

Tags: xml, haskell

I am a complete noob at Haskell and I am trying to do a project.
I need to be able to create an xml based on the user input. 
For example

I ask a user if they want to enter a name, if they choose yes, then it should create this as a simple xml

```
<person>
     <name>Chosen name</name>
</person>
```

Any idea on how I can achieve this? This has to be done **without using xml libraries**

Thank you so much in advance for any answers

I havent really done much as I am not sure how to proceed, this is what I've done so far

```
main = do   
    putStrLn   "Would you like to add a person?"
    putStrLn   "1 = Yes"
    putStrLn   "2 = No"
    choice <-getLine

    --some sort of if statement here to decide what to do next
```

I have also tried to append file this way

```
createName = appendFile "addPerson.xml" openName
openName = "<name>"
```

but I need this to be called once they user enters their name

Comment: Show us what you've tried so far.

Comment: @RobinGreen Hi Robin, do you have some sort of example that you could show me? I am really really grateful to all you guys for the fast response too

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'll give you a little bit of a hint:

```
main = do   
    putStrLn "Would you like to add a person?"
    putStrLn "1 = Yes"
    putStrLn "2 = No"
    choice <- readLn
    case choice of
        1 -> do
            ... -- Add a person
        2 -> do
            ... -- Do not add a person
        _ -> do
            ... -- The user entered an invalid input
```

I recommend that you read [Learn you a Haskell for Great Good](http://learnyouahaskell.com/) so that you can learn basic Haskell syntax and idioms.

Comment: Gabriel, you are my hero. Thank you very much!